# uncommitted new row not visible after add rows programmatically datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i set set datagridview AllowUserToAddRows true but after i add row programmatically, the uncommitted new row not visible, even i focus on last row and press enter, here is the code:

```
OpenFileDialog Open_DLG = new OpenFileDialog();


               Open_DLG.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";


               if (Open_DLG.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
               {
                   string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(Open_DLG.FileName);
                   int RowIndex = 0;
                   int ColumnIndex = 1;
                   
                   foreach (string Line in Lines)
                   {
                       if (ColumnIndex > DataGRD_Comments.Columns.Count - 1)
                       {
                           RowIndex = DataGRD_Comments.Rows.Add();
                           ColumnIndex = 1;
                       }

                       DataGRD_Comments.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex].Value = Line;
                       

                       ColumnIndex++;
                   }


                   
               }
```

also i add columns programmatically,
i want to keep uncommitted new row visible after add rows programmatically? how to do that?
thanks

Comment: what is the use for `if (ColumnIndex > DataGRD_Comments.Columns.Count - 1)` ? Maybe there will never be more than 1 column ? SHould you not check for the number of rows instead of the number of columns ?

Comment: i add row and fill all cells of row then add another row and fill all cells ... and so on, if (ColumnIndex > DataGRD_Comments.Columns.Count - 1) meens rich to last column so add new row and start fill cells

Comment: i have dynamic columns count

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to put all lines from a file into the DataGrid.
I think you need something like this short example.

```
foreach (string Line in Lines)
{
     RowIndex = DataGRD_Comments.Rows.Add();
     DataGRD_Comments.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex].Value = Line;
}
```

Comment: i have more than one columns so i have to increase RowIndex and ColumnIndex as i do in my code

Comment: i have dynamic columns count